# Passing "this" to .on function doesnt seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function:

```
function test(e){
            $('.movie').find('.moreInfo').removeClass('moreInfoShow');
            e.parent().find('.moreInfo').addClass('moreInfoShow');
            $("#movieBox").isotope('reLayout');

            e.parent().find('.moreInfo').css("opacity", "0");
            e.parent().find('.moreInfo').animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
        }
```

which is called by:

```
$("#movieBox").on('mouseover', '.moviePoster', function(event){test($(this));});
```

The issue is that I want the function to be called when the page loads. I need to pass "this" to the function but I have had no luck in getting it to work.

This is what I expected to work:

```
test($(".moviePoster").first());
```

(ALL code is in "$(document).ready" function)

Comment: Please provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: If I am getting your question right, Do `$("#movieBox").find('.moviePoster').trigger('mouseover');` on page load.

Comment: $(this) is passed successfully have a look http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/vPXfz/1/

Comment: If you are expecting `this` to refer to the `.moviePoster` element, then your code is correct. If your code doesn't work then there is some other issue. You have not described what causes you to believe that `this` is not the element you want. You should show your HTML.

Comment: Yes it does refer to .moviePoster, I should rephrase my question. The trigger didn't work due to there being many .moviePoster elements. Even this didnt work: $("#movieBox").find('.moviePoster').first().trigger('mouseover'); What could be the cause?

Comment: What I was trying to do was call a function when page loads instead of triggering events as I hadn't had much luck with triggers in the past.

Comment: My apologies, the issue turned out to be that .ajax call populated the #movieBox and it was not returned on .ready function. I solved my issue by adding the trigger code in the success handler of the .ajax call. @Jashwant, please add the trigger code as answer. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in comments, trigger the `mouseover` event on page load.

```
$("#movieBox").find('.moviePoster').trigger('mouseover');
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Answer (score 1):

W/O fiddle:

Change this:

```
$("#movieBox").on('mouseover', '.moviePoster', function(event){test($(this));});
```

to

```
$("#movieBox").on('mouseover', '.moviePoster', test);
```

Then $(this) inside test function should point to the jQuery object which triggered the event.

Invoking test function in the callback with "test($(this))" will instantly execute the function and not when the event is fired.

Update:

After you did this, you'll need to trigger the mouseover event on page load of course.
See Jashwant's comment on how to do that.

Update I was wrong.

```
function(event){test($(this));}
```

will of course not trigger the callback function instantly. This only would happen if it would be like this:

```
$("#movieBox").on('mouseover', '.moviePoster', test($(this)));
```

Sorry!

Comment: This isn't right. Invoking `test` in the callback will not execute it immediately. It will be invoked when the event is fired. That's why there's an event handler. It handles the event when it occurs.

Comment: I actually had it the way ur suggesting before but it didn't seem to pass "this" or maybe it was another issue. It should work both ways as the function is called  and that's what matter.

Comment: gray state is coming: jsfiddle thinks, I'm right: http://jsfiddle.net/F9R9r/1/ Or am I missing something here?

Comment: gray state is coming you were right. See my update. Thanks and sorry :)